# Can you write from a particular position in a file from c?

Tags: c, file-io

I want to start at a particular offset, write and then at some point read from that same offset and confirm I read what I wrote to the file. The file is in binary. I'm confident I need to use fseek but I may want to call a write several times prior to reading the whole file.

```
write(unsigned long long offset, void* pvsrc, unsigned long long nbytes)

 pFile = fopen("D:\\myfile.bin","wb"); 

 fseek(pFile,offset,SEEK_SET);   
 WriteResult = fwrite (pvsrc, 1, nbytes, pFile); 
 fclose(pFile);
```

Anyone see any issue with this? .. Anyone?

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ftell()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) to tell you your current position in the file, perform some writes and then [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) to the starting position you got with ftell() to read the data that you wrote.

Comment: This needs to be in a class function so I don't want to have to do ftell fseek everytime I want to do something but it will be part of the function itself.

Comment: Then encapsulate the functionality. For example, you can perform all of this in a high level member function. Or, you can break it up and store the position returned by ftell() in a member variable for later use by a member function that reads the data back.

Comment: @Questioneer: you easily can compose a function which will does ftell/write the data/fseek back.

Comment: @Michael: in C, there are no member functions.

Comment: The tags for this question are off. See Questioneer's first comment about adding a class function.

Comment: My current functionality is this: I have a class write function that is given an offset, a pointer to a buffer, and nbytes. Are you saying that fseek(pFile,offset,SEEK_SET) won't work without a ftell? Sorry if I'm confused. My main file function calls will be in my edit above for you to reference.

Comment: fseek will work without ftell, but to know to which offset to seek, you need to capture it at some point. The ftell function can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can use the `pread()` and `pwrite()` functions: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pread

If you are on Windows, you can use the `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` functions with the `lpOverlapped` parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx